# UI freeze onChange event when trying to display an alert

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using react-native-datepicker Modal and onDateChange event im trying to display an altert. But when I do it the alert pops up first and immediately disappears and then freeze the whole UI. My code as bellow.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <DatePicker
                style={{ width:Dimensions.get('window').width/2 - 10}}
                date={this.state.date}
                mode="date"
                placeholder="select date"
                format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                minDate={minimumDate}
                maxDate={currentDate}
                confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                customStyles={{
                    dateIcon: {
                        position: 'absolute',
                        left: 0,
                        top: 4,
                        marginLeft: 0
                    },
                    dateInput: {
                        marginLeft: 36
                    }
                    // ... You can check the source to find the other keys.
                }}
                onDateChange={(date) => { this.dateChange(date)}}
            />
</View>
```

My date change method as bellow

```
 dateChange = (date)=>{
    alert("date is:",date)
 }
```

What am I missing here??

Comment: because `alert` will pause the execution of js. You can take a look at [dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog), may serve your purpose.

Comment: as commented before and also your alert function is incorrect, alert function of window does not takes 2 parameters unlike console. try this instead: alert("date is: " + date )

Comment: Anyway, if you don't want it to pause the main thread, there is [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker)